# Android Studio 2.2.3 themes issue

Tags: android, themes, android-manifest, android-theme

I am not sure what's going on I searched everywhere not what to do. I am trying to change the themes of the app, but only certain themes are available coding

[available themes1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfeiP.jpg)

[available themes2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYonY.jpg)

These are the only themes available if I try using other themes it's causing an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@android:theme/...` as follow
[image]

Comment: I am unable to run the emulator it's starting showing android, not launching the app or showing the display screen what should I do

Comment: yes thanks, but the app shutting down saying app unfortunately stopped if I run it on s7 edge or emulator what should I do

Comment: I am getting a strange error I couldn't figure out what's wrong with it